# Prevent ill-advised imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

Let’s say I have two modules `model` and `utils`, with submodules included.
For maintainability purpose, I want to prevent developers from importing anything from the `model` inside `utils`.

So when module `utils.email.provider_a` calls import `model.foo.bar` it would raise an error.

Comment: "developers" you mean "other maintainers/developers of the two modules"?

Comment: Yes, anyone contributing to the project :-)

Comment: well, have a clear rules/guidelines/code standards for the contributors and proper code review process

Comment: The rule already exists, so I'd better have a tool than a rule

Comment: If the rule exists, why it is not enforced during code review. How do PR get approved/merged in clear violation?

Comment: It's easy to pass by. If a rule state that imports shall be sorted, I'd better use `isort` in `pre-commit`. I see it in the same way, I'd like to prevent it early, before the review, so everyone earn time. But it have to be doable at first :-)